# Estimating width of logistic prediction interval from value of fitted coefficients only

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, epidemiology

On page 1530, left column, of a study by Redline, Tishler, Schluchter, Aylor, Clark and Graham (1999) ([ungated version](http://www.atsjournals.org/doi/full/10.1164/ajrccm.159.5.9809079#.VNzGGjU2tyQ)), one reads:

> Because there is uncertainty regarding the optimal cutoff values of
>   BMI that identify obesity in children, analyses also were repeated for
>   BMI as a continuous variable. This demonstrated that for each
>   increase of 1 kg/m² of BMI above the mean, risk of SDB increased by
>   12%. Use of BMI, rather than obesity defined as a binary variable, did
>   not alter the results of the multiple adjusted logistic regression
>   analyses presented in Table 4.

So based on the fit from the paper above (obtained from a sample of size $n$), all other things being equal, for an increase of 2 kg/m² of BMI above the mean, the risk of SDB is expected to increase by a factor of $\approx 1.12^2$. My question is, what is the expected variation around this expectation? Can an approximation to the width of the prediction interval be deduced from just the numbers given above (e.g. the slope of the variable being changed): the paper gives no other information about this logistic fit (in particular no standard errors around these estimates).

---

I can see that the formula for the distribution of predictors 
in logistic includes the s.e. of the regression coefficients. 
But, conditional on $\pmb x$, $y$ is binomial distributed with 
parameter estimated by $\hat{p}(y|\pmb x)$ so I was wondering whether 
 there was a way to obtain the $\hat{\mbox{var}}(y|\pmb x)$
 from $\hat{p}(y|\pmb x)$ alone.

Comment: Distribution in what sense? Your notation "$\hat{p}(y_j=1)$" indicates an estimated probability. Thus are you asking for the estimation distribution or are you perhaps trying to estimate the value $p(y_j=1)$ within some population?  If the former, which values of the explanatory variables should be used? If the latter, which population?

Comment: You observe that the paper gives no standard errors.  With that being the case, what else do they give that makes you suspect there might be enough to deduce a confidence interval?